# UICollectionView Crashes with Error : Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

Originally my CollectionView was working fine, but I wanted to adjust the width of the item in CollectionView according to the width of the TextLabel in CollectionView, so I added some code and then crashed when the program was initialized:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "OnedaySubTodoCell", for: indexPath) as! SubCell
    let width = 28 + cell.subNameLabel.bounds.size.width
    print("Width: \(width)")
    return CGSize(width: width, height: 20)
}
```

This is an error report and it show in `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {`:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7a00b0018)

This is output:

> Width: 88.0 
>   (lldb)

My class has inherited `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`，I want to know where the problem is.

Comment: You should not access cell in . `sizeForItemAt` method

Comment: @PrashantTukadiyaSo how can I dynamic adjust the width?

Comment: Label is not get initialised  , So you can't access it . check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409390/sizing-uicollectionviewcell-based-on-label-size

Comment: Calling `cell.awakeFromNib()` right after `let cell...` might help.

Comment: Never use `dequeueReusableCell` outside of `cellForItemAt`.

Comment: is your `TextLabel` text dynamic or static ?

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz Dynamic.

Comment: So, the text in label should determine label's width and consequently, label's width should determine items width, right?

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rmaddy and @Prashant pointed out,

> You should not use `cellForItemAt` in `sizeForItemAT` because
>   `sizeForItemAt` is called BEFORE initializing the cell in
>   `cellForItemAt`

And most probably that's the reason for your crash. Coming towards Solution.

I was faced with a similar problem (had to dynamically manage height) and what i did is something like

Calculate the estimated width of your label based on text. use the following string extension

```
//calculates the required width of label based on text. needs height and font of label
extension String {

 func width(withConstrainedHeight height: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {

    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
    let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [.font: font], context: nil)

    return ceil(boundingBox.width)
  }
}
```

---

Now, inside `sizeForItemAt`

```
    //put actual lblHeight here
    let lblHeight = Put_actual_label_height_here // e.g 30

    //put actual label font here
    let lblFont =   Put_actual_label_font_here  //e.g UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)

  //calculate required label width
    let lblRequiredWidth = yourLabel's_Text_String.width(withConstrainedHeight: lblHeight, font: lblFont)

    //you may want to return size now 
    let height = yourItemsHeight
    return CGSize(width: lblRequiredWidth, height: height)
```

Now that you have got the required width of your label, you can adjust the size of the item based on label's width.

Hope that helps. Let me know if you need any help. Thanks

Comment: title is your label's text string. see updated answer

Comment: If I don't use `cellForItemAt` or `dequeueReusableCell`, how can I get the label?

Comment: how did you design ? storyboards or programmatically?

Comment: design in the storyboard.

Comment: well, i need to see the design and constraints to answer perfectly. 
You just need label `height` and `font`. you have set the constraints so you know what will be the height and what is its font. 

use this information

Comment: Yes, constraints and fonts I know, I mean to ask, in this method, how do I get `Label` this thing, get the label I can call the `width` method.

Comment: You don't need to get label and you should not. just use the font and height that you have set in storyboard to get dynamic width of text

Comment: Excuse me, I am a bit dizzy, what should I write on that label？

Comment: I used to get the cell, then using the cell.mylabel statement to get the label, but now I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @JakeTo. i already mentioned you DON'T need to get the cell or the label in `sizeForItemAt`. 
Just use the code that i mentioned for `sizeForItemAt` in the answer. Put the actual label height and font there and you should be good to go.

Comment: Good to hear that. Happy coding :)